# Confused about type of expression

Tags: f#

I have a function that I think should return a type T. However, it is reporting that is returns ( T -> T ), which sure seems like s function in itself to me. Here is the code:

```
let setContent content cell = { cell with Content = content }

let destroy = setContent Crater

let detonateMine cell = 
    function 
    | { Content = Mine } -> 
        destroy cell
    | { Content = Crater } -> 
        let errMessage = sprintf "The cell has already been denotated. (%i, %i)" cell.Location.X cell.Location.Y
        invalidOp errMessage
    | _ -> 
        let errMessage = 
            sprintf "The cell cannot be denotated. It does not contain a mine. (%i, %i)" cell.Location.X 
                cell.Location.Y
        invalidOp errMessage
```

setContent is T -> T

destroy is T -> T

I have tests for destroy and the returned values are T.

However, the type of detonate is `cell:T -> _arg1:T -> T`. Where is the _arg1 coming from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here, the word `function` doesn't do what you want.  Instead, it creates essentially an anonymous function.

In general

```
function | ...
```

is equivalent to

```
fun y -> match y with | ...
```

(the `_arg1` corresponds to the `y` I've added)

In your case changing `function` to:

```
match cell with
```

should do what you want.